# Linq expression builder, add conditional in divide case

Tags: .net, linq, expression, divide

As part of a larger set of expressions, we have our divide case.  It's simple enough

```
protected override Expression BuildDivideExpression(Expression left, Expression right)
{           
    return Expression.Divide(left, right);
}
```

I'd like to change it so that it returns 0 if left is 0, and as is if left != 0..  Something like this:

```
protected override Expression BuildDivideExpression(Expression left, Expression right)
{
    return Expression.Condition(left != 0, Expression.Constant(0), Expression.Divide(left, right))
}
```

But I can't figure out the conditional bit currently shown as "left != 0"

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean if right is equal to zero you want the result to be zero. So you want to use [Expression.Equal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352749.aspx) like so

```
protected override Expression BuildDivideExpression(Expression left, Expression right)
{
    return Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(right, Expression.Constant(0)),
                                Expression.Constant(0), 
                                Expression.Divide(left, right))
}
```

Comment: Actually in our case, I did mean the left side (i.e. not trying to do a divide by 0 check), but your answer does what I wanted, thanks!